# WPF custom context menu click event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, windowsformshost

I'm creating a custom context menu using a WebBrowser inside a WindowsFormsHost. But for some reason, the click event I assign to the menu item is not firing. Other events I assign are.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
    System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
    System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem()
    {
        Text = "Add comment"
    };

    // not firing
    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(menuItem_Click);
    // is firing
    menuItem.Select += new System.EventHandler(menuItem_Click);

    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    browser.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

    // is firing
    browser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
    // is firing
    browser.HandleCreated += new System.EventHandler(browser_HandleCreated);

    windowsFormsHost.Child = browser;
    browser.DocumentText = "Test";
}

void browser_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I just ran into the same problem.  I fixed it by using a ContextMenuStrip instead of a ContextMenu.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip webBrowserMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem refreshItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem("Refresh");
refreshItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(refreshMenuItem_Click);
webBrowserMenu.Items.Add(refreshItem);

webBrowser1.ContextMenuStrip = webBrowserMenu;
```